# Create Custom Fields for Rails module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a User model with some user information like dexterity, strength and more. A user has many inventory items that also have extra strength, dexterity etc ..

What is the better way of getting a User object with those values combined ? I mean, something like `current_user.dexterity = current_user.dexterity + current_user.inventory_item.dexterity`, but in a much better fashion, combined for all attributes, in an easy to access object.

Also, i think that find would be important here, since i would also like to :include some more information as :game_item (the static representation of an item in the database that corresponds to an inventory_item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inventory_items

  def dexterity
    read_attribute(:dexterity)+inventory_items.includes(:game_items).inject(0){ |s,i| s += i.dexterity)
  end
end
```

This code will read a user's dexterity and then include all inventory items and join them with their appropriate game items, and then calculate the sum of the items' dexterities and add that to the total.  Another alternative for calculating a sum is this:

```
current_user.inventory_items.all.sum(&:dexterity)
```

Comment: great examples thanx :) I think that latter one is the easiest and the best for this case.